# "Simple" Rectangle Collision Detection: Why doesn't my code work?

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

Hey guys, please take a look at my code and see what's wrong here. I looked at the docs and everything and it seems like this should work.

```
public Boolean CollisionTest (Rect one, Rect two) {
        if (one.intersect(two)) {
            collided = true;
        } else {
            collided = false;
        }
        return(collided);
    }
```

Should this not return if two rectangles collide? The reason I am doubting this I am having some null pointer exception inside my Main Thread (it is stopping on my finally statement for my game loop thread) errors when debugging and when I do not use this function it is fine.

Very weird, also I would appreciate if anyone could post links to useful collision detection tutorials. I want to deal with my own collision detection and not use outside libraries.

Thanks EVERYONE!

Comment: What does `intersect` return when a bigger rectangle completely covers a smaller rectangle, but their edges do not intersect?

Comment: Side question - why not just {return one.intersect(two);} ?

Comment: Why return `Boolean` instead of `boolean`?  Where is the variable declaration of `collided`?  Have you tried `assert( one!=null && two!=null )`?

Comment: collided is a global boolean variable. What exactly does assert do? Are you saying I should make sure Rect one and two are not null before checking collision?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the Android Developers documentation for the `intersect` function:

> If the specified rectangle intersects this rectangle, return true **and set this rectangle to that intersection**, otherwise return false and do not change this rectangle.

The part that I added emphasis to means that your `one` parameter could be changed if the rectangles do intersect -- which I'm guessing is how it's somehow getting set to `null`, and causing your error later on in the game loop.

The documentation also states:

> To just test for intersection, use `intersects()`.

A description of the `Rect.intersects(Rect a, Rect b)` method is [available here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect%29).

If we modify your method to use `Rect.intersects`, it would look like this:

```
public Boolean CollisionTest (Rect one, Rect two) {
        return Rect.intersects(one, two);
    }
```

At this point you could probably get rid of `CollisionTest` altogether and just call `Rect.intersects` directly -- unless at some point you wanted to implement your own collision detection. In that case, you'd just have to modify this one method. It's up to you, really.

Comment: I saw that but I didn't realize you could just say Rect.intersects... I didn't really know how to go about it. Thanks this is very helpful and yes I agree that this would make my method obsolete.

Comment: Excellent answer, but wow.  "intersect" has a side effect rather than returning the intersection?  That's surprisingly bad api design.  I'd expect better from Google.   Reminds me of C.

Comment: @Kirk No problem. The reason you can just say `Rect.intersects` is that `intersects` is a **static** method, whereas `intersect` is an **instance** method. This is an important distinction to understand, read some of the answers posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169378/c-method-can-be-made-static-but-should-it) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618969/java-when-to-make-methods-static-v-instance) for some clarification, and if you have any questions I can think of a [good place to ask...](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @CPerkins I was definitely surprised when I looked it up to confirm, especially since their names are very close (and `intersect` returns a `bool` as well).

Comment: btw I didn't use new Rect for the Rect I was assigning stuff. That is why I was getting that error. (i'm a noob!) LIVE AND LEARN

Answer (score 1):

You could write a check like this:

```
public boolean CollisionTest(Rect one, Rect two) {
  return one.left <= two.right && one.right >= two.left &&
      one.top <= two.bottom && one.bottom >= two.top;
}
```

Comment: Would this be better than Rects intersects method? I guess depending on what sides are intersecting I am going to want to change the path of my sprites so I may want to do it here.

Comment: Actually it's virtually identical to Rect.intersects as you can see from the Android source http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/graphics/java/android/graphics/Rect.java&q=rect%20intersects%20java&l=442  The idea was just to show you how it's done. Mine considers 'on the line' to be a collision and Android's doesn't (`>=` not `>`) but that's neither here nor there.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have not defined collided over here in the function. Is that defined in the global space or as an instance variable.

Also you can shorten your code

```
public Boolean CollisionTest (Rect one, Rect two) {
    if (one.intersect(two)) {
        collided = true;
    } else {
        collided = false;
    }
    return(collided);
}
```

as

```
return one.intersect(two);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not familiar with the `Rect` API but @Donut has answered this part well. Since you're also wondering about collision detection I will leave two very good tutorials about it.

I do have experiences in making a tile map system and a basic collision detection for a game, in Java (on an Android phone). [This](http://www.parallelrealities.co.uk/tutorials/intermediate/tutorial14.php) and [this](http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/tut01.html) were very good tutorials and pretty straightforward and they contains basic collision detection.

Comment: Thanks these seem like they can be very helpful.